# `postman` - how to fix this "Could not get any response"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, postman

What is this issue? how to fix this. one of other app works well. but i am facing this issue with another api, but i don't know the issue what I am facing here?

any one help me?

here is my code :

```
var 
    express     = require('express'),
    path        = require('path'),
    morgan      = require('morgan'),
    bodyParser  = require('body-parser'),
    port        = process.env.PORT || 8080,
    mongoose    = require('mongoose'),
    openApi     = require('./app/api/openApi'),
    familyApi   = require('./app/api/familyApi'),
    app         = express();

    //app config;-

var base        = app.use( express.static( __dirname + '/public') );
var reqest      = app.use( morgan('dev') );
var jsonParse   = app.use( bodyParser.json() );
var urlParse    = app.use( bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));


app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type,Authorization');
    next();
});

// mongoose.connect('mongodb://node:noder@ds013456.mlab.com:13456/practical');

    mongoose.connect( 'mongodb://3gwebtrain:root@ds021166.mlab.com:21166/students', function( err ) {

        if( err ) console.log( err );

        console.log( 'connection successful!' );

    });

    //calling api from another files;
    openApi( express, app );
    // familyApi( express, app );


    app.get('/', function( req, res ) {
        res.sendFile( path.join( __dirname + '/public/app/views/index.html') );
    });

    app.listen( port );
    console.log('app is listening at', port );
```

my open api file :

```
"use strict";

var User = require('../models/userModel');

module.exports = function( express, app ){

    var openApi = express.Router();

    openApi.post('/create', function( req, res ){

        var user = new User();

        user.name = req.body.name;
        user.username = req.body.username;
        user.password = req.body.password;

        console.log( user.name, user.username, user.password  + '\n' + user );


        user.save(function(err) {

            if (err) {

                // duplicate entry
                if (err.code == 11000)

                    return res.json({ success: false, message: 'A user with that username already exists. '});

                else

                    return res.send(err);
            }

            res.json({ message: 'User created!' });
        });

    });

    //prefixing the open apis
    app.use('/open', openApi);

    return openApi;

}
```

[image: postman error]

Comment: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/506

Comment: No, the matter is, I am using the same postman for other api's too.. but rest of them works. I strongly guess, something wrong with my code. any one figure it out?

Comment: why you are requesting this  ?
http://localhost:8080/open/create

Answer (score 0):

Try this in postman

```
localhost:8080/create
```

Comment: Since, i would like to differenciate the api whichever belongs to without authentication, i am added a prefix like this : `app.use('/open', openApi);` - what is the issue in this?

Comment: `app.use` is behave like a middleware so all your request use open

Comment: no issue by using this it better if you differentiate your route by routes name like `/open/create` in your route not use as middleware so you can use other routes without using open.It depends upon your routing flow

Comment: agree, one of you able to identify the issue here?